# how can i acces to my wordpress project in a remote in the same network by typing remoteName/projectName?

Tags: wordpress, ip, remote-access, remote-server

i want to acces to my wordpress project which is installed in a remote in the same network via the computer name  or ipadress ! i use wamp server and  windows server 2008 standard r2 .
how can i acces to my project by typing  remoteName/projectName ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to Dashboard > Settings > General
2. In the 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' text box replace localhost with your IP adress.
3. Save changes.

This solves your problem.

Comment: this allow the acces to remote via @ip but i  can't use the remote name.
for exemple :
remoteName/project1/home ??